# choosing a threshold value to compute the similarity between two images in matlab

Tags: matlab, information-retrieval, similarity, threshold

In order to compute the distance (D) between the query image feature with each image database feature and display (n-similarity images to the user).

I try to use the following approach:

I choose two threshold values `(T1, T2)`. For the first one I keep all the distances (`D2`) which are larger than (`T1`) in a variable say (`L1`), and keep all the distances (`D2`) which are smaller than (`T2`) in another variable, say (`L2`). Then, I compute the similarity measure by:

```
S(i) = L2 * average(D3) / (L3^2)
```

Please, how could I choose these thresholds? Is there is any method to compute the threshold value or should I choose it randomly?

Comment: Have you tried experimenting?

Comment: أه  reve_etrange, Yes I do that by experimenting many value but I look for any method to choose the threshold value... thanks and Sorry for being late in reply

Comment: I meant that since there is no _a priori_ way to choose a threshold, you will need to pick a value that gives empirically good results.  For example, you could create a gold standard by hand using a subset of your image database and then (programmatically) choose a threshold that jives well with the standard.

Comment: Also, some distance measures allow a heuristic choice, e.g. cosine distance of vectors (`1 - (x dot y) / (norm(x) * norm(y))`) in two or three dimensions can be visualized pretty well.  So you might decide that pi/4 (45 deg) is the biggest angle between 'similar' vectors and use a value of `1 - .707 = .293` as a threshold.  In higher dimensional spaces this is more difficult of course.  

When you performed your experiments did you check how well each value performed?  Were similar (to the eye) images selected over different ones?

Answer (score 0):

I have trouble understanding your expressions. What exactly is `D3`? I assume the index `i` in `S(i)` refers to the i'th image in the database. Is D or L indexed by `i` also? In general for problems like these, what is more important is choosing the right similarity measure, and then comparing different approaches with methods like the [ROC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic) and [Precision-Recall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall) curves. You should leave out worrying about the threshold until then.

Comment: thank you for replying I would like to inform u   .. that I am already used Precision-Recall curve but I look for another methods in order to compare between the results .. Now I will try to use the ROC curve and see the results..

Comment: For specific quantitative measures, also try the area under ROC and the F-1 score. (Maximum Precision x Recall acheived anywhere on the curve)